Pull parameter from parent page a razor component is on
Here's a portion of my page.
@page "/campaigns/{id:int}"
@inject ICampaignService CampaignService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Campaign Detail Page</PageTitle>
@if (campaign == null)
{
    <span>@message</span>
    <p><button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => ShowAll())">Back to Campaigns</button></p>
}
else
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="container p-3 my-3 border">
                <h1>@campaign.Title</h1>
                <p>@campaign.Description</p>
                <p>This container has a border and some extra padding and margins.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <ChaptersByCampaignList />

Here's the ChaptersByCampaignList component.
@inject IChapterService ChapterService

<h3>Chapters</h3>
<ul class="list-group">
    @if (ChapterService.ChaptersByCampaign == null)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">No Chapters</li>
    }
    else
    {
        @foreach (var dbObject in ChapterService.ChaptersByCampaign)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">@dbObject.OrderIndex - @dbObject.Title</li>
        }
    }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await ChapterService.GetAllByCampaignId(Id);
    }
}

The ChaptersService has these snippets of code.
public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
public List<Chapter> ChaptersByCampaign { get; set; }

public async Task GetAllByCampaignId(int id)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Chapter>>($"api/chapters/campaign/{id}");
    if (response != null)
        ChaptersByCampaign = response;
}

First, the ChaptersByCampaignList component doesn't seem to be getting the CampaignId passes through the URL, through debugging I can see it keeps being set to 0. I'm needing to get id from the passes URL @page "/campaigns/{id:int}"
Thanks!

Of course as soon as I submitted this post, I had an idea. Simply doing this
<ChaptersByCampaignList Id="@Id" />
Passes the parameter along to the component.
